# pH notation in text

Tags: ph, notation

When referring to units of pH in continuous text (i.e. not in a table), which is the recommended usage?

- pH 7 to pH 8
- pH 7 to 8

What about when the term "pH" has already been mentioned in the text?

- the pH was increased from 7 to 8
- the pH was increased from pH 7 to 8
- the pH was increased from pH 7 to pH 8
- the pH value was increased from 7 to 8

Comment: Using pH twice in any of those sentences is redundant.

Comment: Additionally, would it be correct to refer to pH as a measure of acidity? Or would this be ambiguous with the acid dissociation constant?

Comment: If your readers are chemists then saying that "pH as a measure of acidity" is ludicrous. If you are writing an article for a newspaper about mine water discharge then through the phrase into the article.

Comment: In a dilute solution, is not pH an appropriate measure of acidity? Constant references to hydrogen ion activity become tedious.

Comment: $$\ce{<-->[He went that way!]}$$ The point is that chemists know pH is a measure of acidity. You don't have to explain it every time you use the term.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were saying.

Comment: I was thinking more as in whether acidity cambiguously refer to either pH or $\mathrm{K_a}$.

Answer (score 3):

E.g. in the ACS style guide, 3rd edition, rather only the pH symbol itself is focused on, with some examples of “half intervals” ([or how to name that?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3709831/whe-is-a-term-for-half-interval)) notation:

> … Use roman type for pH and pOH; always use lowercase for “p”; always capitalize “H” and “OH”.
>
> Solutions were titrated to pH >11.
>
> The UV spectra were measured at pH 6.
>
> A pOH of <12 was acceptable.

I couldn't find any explicit recommendation for notation of pH ranges. In [*Measurement of pH. Definition, Standards, and Procedures* (IUPAC Recommendations 2002)](https://doi.org/10.1351/pac200274112169) several “notations” are used in text, e.g.

at p. 2179 (11 of 32):

> … between pH 3 and 10 …

p. 2184 (16):

> … pH(S) values of … are in the range 3 ≤ pH(S) ≤ 11 …

p. 2199 (31)

> … in the pH range 3−10 …

Answer (score 0):

**pH 7**

The usage is inconsistent with pH being a dimensionless quantity. It would be logical to write "the pH is 7", or "the pH is in the range from 5 to 8". This would correspond to the symbolic notation:

$$\mathrm{pH} = 7$$
$$\mathrm{pH} = [5,8]\quad \text{ or }\quad 5 < \mathrm{pH} < 8$$

where [5,8] indicates a range.

Instead, usage like "at pH 5" are common and sanctioned by the ACS style guide. It's a bit like saying "I am looking for size 11 shoes" instead of "The size of my shoes is 11".

**pH 7 to 8**

When giving a range of pH values, there is no reason to repeat pH. pH is the quantity, and it is clear that you are giving a range for that quantity. This is different from giving a range of lengths, or a length with a standard deviation. In that case, both lengths, or the length and its standard deviation need to have units, e.g.

$$l_1 = \pu{2.3 cm}\ ..\ \pu{2.4 cm}$$

$$l_2 = \pu{21.7 cm} \pm \pu{0.3 cm}$$

Of course, you can leave out the duplicated unit by using parentheses:

$$l_1 = (\pu{2.3}\ ..\ \pu{2.4})\pu{cm}$$

$$l_2 = (21.7 \pm 0.3)\pu{cm}$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\mathrm{pH} \in [5,8]$ ?